# Filter multiple columns by value using Checkbox group

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

How can I use a checkbox group to filter several columns by value? 
See example below: I want to return only the rows for which the columns indicated by the checkbox group have the value "yes".

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

```{r}
checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
choices = list("col1", "col2"))
```

```{r}
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),c("no","yes","yes"),c("no","no","yes"))
colnames(df)<-c("id","col1","col2")
```
```{r}
renderDataTable({
    df        
})
```
````

ie when selecting "col1', the output should contain only row row#2 and 3,
when selecting "col2', the output should be: row#3,
when selecting both "col1" and "col2", the output should be: row#2 and 3.

I could write an if statement for each variable but I'd rather not (I have 10 or so). Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you'd need to develop a filter condition for your data based off of the input values.  I'm going to use the `dplyr` any the `filter_at` function to show you how.

This also incorporates some reactive concepts used in shiny.  If you're not too familiar with them, I would recommend doing some reading.

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
choices = list("col1", "col2"))
```

```{r}
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3), "col1" = c("no","yes","yes"),"col2" = c("no","no","yes"))
```
```{r}
renderDataTable({
    filter_at(df, input$checkGroup, any_vars(. == "yes"))       
})
```
````

Within the last code chunk is where you'd use `filter_at`, and since you're doing this based off of inputs, it needs to be within the `renderDataTable` reactive function.

What this does is:

1. filter your `df`
2. at the variables in your selections from `input$checkGroup` (your checkbox input)
3. selecting any variables from the indicated selection that are equivalent to "yes". (e.g `any_vars(. == "yes))`. The dot is a placeholder for the variables indicated in the inputs you selected.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks! Btw I've included a test to check if there is a selection made because when not, an error was given. Ie: if(!is.null(input$checkGroup){..}